# Multi line captions for ApplicationBarIconButton

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I know, the guidelines advice to keep captions to one line, but still:

Is there a workaround to add (automatic/manual) line breaks to an ApplicationBarIconButton's text caption? E.g. for `<shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="…" Text="button with long title" />`, the button's text only shows "button with" when rendered.

(on my German WP7 for example, there are multiline captions in the MS mail application).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `&#x0d;` in your string in XAML where you'd use `\r` in C#.

Something like:

```
Text="button with&#x0d;long title"
```

If there's enough height, it should work fine. If not, you'd need to change the template for `ApplicationBarIconButton`

Comment: Thank you XAMeLi, while this seems like the correct character for a line break, I get a System.InvalidOperationException now, when running the app, telling me: "Text cannot contain multiple lines". So, obviously, Microsoft is actively preventing line breaks :( .

Comment: Bummer. Can't understand why Microsoft keep "dumbifying" their frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `"sample" + System.Environment.NewLine + "text"`.

Comment: How should I put that into the XAML?

Comment: You can load it from C# code, just after InitializeComponent().